# Emacs / vim quick copy paste

Tags: vim, emacs, copy-paste, spacemacs

I'm trying to make a transition to emacs (using evil mode/vim keybindings) and I'm having a hard time feeling more efficient/productive than if I just used the mouse. Here is an example of a situation where I find myself really slow:

```
for i in range(self.allData.shape[0]):
    self.correctSequence = self.displayNumbers(i, self.allData)
    self.userSequence = self.numberEntry()

    self.allData.set_value(i, 'userSequence', ''.join(self.userSequence))

    if len(self.correctSequence) != len(self.userSequence):
        self.allData.set_value(i, 'correct', 0)
    else:
        if list(reversed(self.correctSequence)) == self.userSequence:
            self.allData.set_value(i, 'correct', 1)
        else:
            self.allData.set_value(i, 'correct', 0)
```

It would be very common for me to have to change the first 4 instances of `self.allData` to something else (`self.testData`, for example), leaving the last 2 untouched.

Normally this wouldnt be too bad with a mouse. For example, I could replace the first `allData` with `testData`, copy it, use the mouse to the next 3 occurences and just hit CTRL-V for each one. Or better yet, just use multiple cursors in sublime/atom and replace all 4 in one go

I use spacesmacs in emacs with vim keybindings. So, in emacs I find myself having to do something like the following:

1. `SPC-SPC a` (avy jump to words beginning with a)
2. `cw testData`

Repeat those 2 steps once for each word I want to replace

This seems really inefficient and I'm wondering: am I just using an inefficient method? Is there a faster way to do what I want?

It seems that even if I managed to complete those steps really fast (4 times), theres still A LOT more typing one would have to do, and I fail to see how this would be faster than just reaching for the mouse. Yes, one could make the argument that I'm losing time by constantly reaching for the mouse, but in my mind I'm saving typing time by reaching for the mouse because I can just hit CTRL-V a few times to achieve what I want. Where exactly are the vim speed gains in a situation like this?

Comment: As you mention multiple cursors, you can have that in Emacs too: https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to [replace](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Replace.html#Replace), you can use [`query-replace`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html), and replace the word one by one.

You can use [`replace-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unconditional-Replace.html#Unconditional-Replace) too, but remember to limit replacement to part of the buffer, activate the region around that part.

Anyway, these commands could prevent you from finding the word by your eyes, moving cursor by mouse and moving your hand back to keybaord. And they could avoid probable overlook too. At least I don't want to leave my hands from the keyboard when typing. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how "vim-like" Spacemacs is, but you *could* do it like this in Vim:

```
/all<CR>
cgntest<Esc>
.
.
.
```

or:

```
/all<CR>
cetestData<Esc>
n.
n.
n.
```

or:

```
:,$s/allD/testD/gc<CR>
```

Maybe one of these methods works in Spacemacs too?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the usual (and generally the best) answer, `query-replace` (see @songyuanyao's answer), you can use the **secondary selection** to advantage to selectively paste the same thing at various places.  Unlike the *region*, the secondary selection is unrelated to the cursor position (aka *point*), so it is always available regardless of where the cursor is.

And unlike query-replacing, you can paste it on demand, instead of having to answer for each matching occurrence.  If you use [delete-selection mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Using-Region.html) then just select some text to replace and paste the secondary selection to replace it.

You can set and paste the secondary selection using the mouse - see [Secondary Selection](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection) on the Emacs Wiki, and see the Emacs manual, node [Secondary Selection](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Secondary-Selection.html).

If you use library [`second-sel.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/second-sel.el) then you can use the secondary selection from the keyboard as well, and get a lot more use out of it.